# "last reboot" command not returning correct date

Tags: ubuntu

When I run "last reboot" on my pi (running ubuntu) it returns "Fri Jul 31 17:11" which is not at all the date, however, "date" returns the correct date it is currently "Thu Nov  5 17:07:00" is there a way to fix this so I can properly see the last reboot time of my pi

Comment: Systemd broke that `last reboot` stuff. Try using `uptime` and `uptime -s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration to systemd with Raspbian Stretch broke the old `last reboot` stuff. You'll get what you need from the `uptime` and `uptime -s` commands.